# How to implement Connexion in respect to FastAPI

Tags: connexion

Am new in FastAPI, but I have managed to create  and simulate simple fastAPI code through POSTMAN and i have experienced them through Swagger Editor

Need your help on how Connexion work in respect to FastAPI.

I have tried to read many article regarding this but most of them were not helpful.